# Passing variable from JavaScript to servlet

Tags: java, javascript, jsp, servlets

I've used JavaScript in my JSP page to process get data of the div tag:

```
var script = ace.edit("editor");
var myDivText = script.getValue();
```

Now I want to pass myDivText to my `servlet.java`. Till today I've passed it as below

```
window.open('http://XXX.XX.XXX.XX:8800/FirstServlet/mygeco?mytxt=' + myDivText,'resizable=yes');
```

But now, I had to include a few input forms and now I am calling my servlet through a submit mechanism, so how do I pass myDivText to servlet.java without using the above method?

==============================EDIT==========================

My form looks as follows:

```
<form method="post" name="myform" action="upload" target="_top" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<li>Left File :  <input type="file" name="dataFile1" id="fileChooser1" /></li>
<li>Right File : <input type="file" name="dataFile2" id="fileChooser2" /></li>
<li>Config File :<input type="file" name="dataFile3" id="fileChooser3" /></li>
<li><input type="hidden" name="myField" id="myfield" value="" /></li>
</form>
```

#### Submitting form through JavaScript:

```
var scc1 = document.getElementById("box");
scc1.innerHTML = scc1.innerHTML + "<br>" + "<span class='blue'>Uploading files, the page might refresh</span>";
var thetxt = scc1.innerHTML;
document.getElementById('myField').value = thetxt; 
document.myform.submit();
```

#### Getting data in Servlet.java

```
String mydiv = request.getParameter("myField");
request.setAttribute("mydiv", mydiv);
```

Comment: use a hidden field within a form to pass it..

Comment: How? I've no idea of that method and that is exactly why I've posted this question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could give your hidden field an id:

.html file

Your form

```
<form action="">
<input type="hidden" name="myField" id="myField" value="" />
</form>
```

and then when you want to assign its value:

Your Javascipt

```
document.getElementById('myField').value = myDivText;
```

send the form with an action..

And at the action page your retrieve it using `request.getParameter("myField")`

Hope it helps

**UPDATE**

Hope this links help
[Multipart/form-data how to get parameter hidden](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20827284/multipart-form-data-how-to-get-parameter-hidden)

[How to upload files to server using JSP/Servlet?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2422468/how-to-upload-files-to-server-using-jsp-servlet)

Comment: Just a moment, trying it..I'll let you know soon.

Comment: Hey the form itself is not getting submitted. When I click submit nothing is happening.

Comment: @Zedai `<input type="submit" value"submit">` did u try this?

Comment: Just check I've just updated my code.

Comment: @Zedai is it compulsory to send the form via javascript?

Comment: Yes. I do some validation stuff related to those files

Comment: now i get it,it is because of enctype=multipart...you will get null values at the next page..find out how to retrieve form values for multipart forms..

Comment: i have added some links regarding the multipart...just check if they help..

Comment: or else you could use sessions instead of complicating it...

Comment: I am not even able to submit the form, just nothin happens when I click the button. So you think all this problem is caused by multi part messages? let me remove that and ckeck.

Comment: if u r using chrome.press ctrl+shift+i and go to the console and check if u getting any error in ur javascript...probably some error is taking place before the form.submit

Answer (score -1):

Create a form and set the values through javascript and submit the form.

```
<form action='<url>' method="POST">
<input type="hidden" name="divtext"/>
</form>
```

And in JS

```
form = document.getElementById("formId"); // or directly through dom
// set the values.
form.submit();
```